# How do I get a resolution higher than 1024x768 in VirtualBox?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, resolution, windows-10-v1709

I have a Windows 10 1709 guest on a Windows 10 20H2 host with Guest Additions installed, but the resolution can't go higher than 1024x768. How can I get the resolution to be higher if I'm using VirtualBox?

Answer (score 0):

This is only a guess.  Please tell me if it works and I will clean up this post.

1. Shut down the VM.
2. Go to the display entry under the VM settings.
3. Try changing "VMSVGA" to "VBoxSVGA".  If that isn't the case, play with different settings here.

[image]

Like I said, this is only a guess but I have had this problem before and this is what solved it for me.

GOOD LUCK! :)

Answer (score 0):

Before you start the guest, increase its video memory by adjusting the slider in the VirtualBox Manager.

Or, issue the following command in a terminal:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "Name of VM" --vram 128
```

Then you start the guest.

Comment: It didn't work. I turned on 3D accerelation and tried upping the VRAM to 256 after that, but it didn't work either.